# REPLACE function but with entire column - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I learned about the `select replace('string','to be replaced','with this')` function, but I'm wondering is there a way I can do something to a whole column, like this

```
select replace(table.column1,'replace this', 'with this');
```

Right now, the command is returning `Query 1 ERROR: Unknown table 'private_db' in field list`

Comment: If it's anything like Oracle then indeed that would be normal usage - so something like select replace(column1, 'replace this', 'with this') from table;

Comment: Ie instead of just selecting the column value you are applying a function to that value in each returned row, so this can be part of a normal query with other columns selected, other tables joined and any where clause etc

Comment: it returns ```Query 1 ERROR: Unknown table 'private_db' in field list```

Comment: It returns that if you try the select suggested by me and Barmar? Seems odd, but I don't use MySql (the reason I didn't try adding an answer, just a comment). The error message does suggest a missing from clause though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `FROM` clause.

```
SELECT replace(column1, 'replace this', 'with this') AS new_column1
FROM yourTable
```

This will return all the values in `column1` with the replacement made.